# Possible to pass arguments to emacsclient alternate-editor?

Tags: emacsclient, command-line-arguments

Currently this works:

```
emacsclient ..args.. --alternate-editor=some_editor
```

However this does not:

```
emacsclient ..args.. --alternate-editor="some_editor --args"
```

Is there a way to call the alternate-editor with arguments?

Comment: Support for this was added in Emacs 26 ([98f01a13a3](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/?h=emacs-26&id=98f01a13a3bf2a4db2dcc82a342ee017326de732), [bug#25082](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25082)), which is currently available at http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/.